# How can I darken the navigation bar when presenting slides with Google Slides?

Tags: navigation-bar, google-slides

How can I darken the navigation bar when presenting slides with Google Slides?

For example in the following screenshot I want to have the white navigation bar on the right to be visible to be dark:

[image]

I tried to use the Navigation Bar application to darken the navigation bar: this works until I open Google Slides, which turns the navigation bar white again.

[image]

I use Android 9 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Comment: When you say presenting, how are you doing it (mobile screen, Chromecast, Samsung screen share)? Also have you tried using Accessibility in Settings or set the Navigation Bar to gestures rather than buttons?

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, I'm sharing my screen through a videoconferencing program (BlueJeans). I have just tried using the gestures for the navigation bar: there is still a white band on the right but it's an improvement. What do you mean by using accessibility in settings?

Comment: In Samsung there are additional settings for visibility/themes in `Settings->Accessibility->Visibility Enhancements` which include Themes and color modifications. Just another thing to look at to see if anything works for you. But probably the gesture indicators are your best path for minimizing the navigation bar.